# python tensorflow - running identical code on mac and ubuntu - ubuntu throws an error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tensorflow, numpy-ndarray

I am running an identical neural network model on mac and ubuntu. The NN runs 3 times inside a loop and outputs the predictions and accuracy. Here's the code:

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import style
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K
import os

#%matplotlib inline
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

def neural_net(set_val, epoch_val, batch_val, label_val):
    sess = tf.Session()
    K.set_session(sess)
    server = tf.train.Server.create_local_server()
    sess = tf.Session(server.target)
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init_op)

    def neural_net_1(label1, pred_1):

        data_num_train = pd.read_csv(str(set_val) + 'final_train_set_all_2.csv')
        data_num_test = pd.read_csv(str(set_val) + 'final_test_set_all_2.csv')

        scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))

        # Train Data
        features_train = data_num_train.drop([label1], axis=1, errors='ignore')
        features_train = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(features_train))
        scale_num_data_train = pd.concat([data_num_train[label1], features_train], axis=1)
        dtrain_train, dtest_train = train_test_split(scale_num_data_train, test_size=0.01, random_state=575)
        X_train = dtrain_train.drop([label1], axis=1, errors='ignore')
        y_train = dtrain_train[label1]

        # Test Data
        features_test = data_num_test.drop([label1], axis=1, errors='ignore')
        features_test = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(features_test))
        scale_num_data_test = pd.concat([data_num_test[label1], features_test], axis=1)
        dtrain_test, dtest_test = train_test_split(scale_num_data_test, test_size=0.99, random_state=575)
        X_test = dtest_test.drop([label1], axis=1, errors='ignore')
        y_test = dtest_test[label1]

        # initiate model
        model = Sequential()

        # Input Layer 1
        model.add(Dense(256, input_dim=1970, init='uniform'))
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(Activation('tanh'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))

        # Hidden Layer 2
        model.add(Dense(256, init='uniform'))
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(Activation('tanh'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))

        # Hidden Layer 3
        model.add(Dense(256, init='uniform'))
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(Activation('tanh'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))

        # Hidden Layer 4
        model.add(Dense(256, init='uniform'))
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(Activation('tanh'))

        # Output Layer 5
        model.add(Dense(10, init='uniform'))
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(Activation('softmax'))

        model.summary()
        rms_prop = RMSprop(lr=0.0001, rho=0.9, epsilon=None, decay=0.0)
        model.compile(optimizer=rms_prop, loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
        model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=epoch_val, batch_size=batch_val, shuffle=True)

        scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=batch_val)
        print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))

        acc_random, accuracy_dict = ("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1] * 100)).split(" ", 1)
        accuracy_dict = accuracy_dict.replace('%', '')
        accuracy_dict = {str(pred_1): accuracy_dict}
        accuracy_df = pd.DataFrame(data=accuracy_dict, index=[0])
        accuracy_df.to_csv('mid_accuracy' + str(set_val) + '_' + label1 + '_' + str(pred_1) + '.csv')

        pred = model.predict_classes(X_test)
        print(pred)
        print(type(pred))

        # output: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

        Xtest = scaler.inverse_transform(X_test)
        Xtest = pd.DataFrame(data=Xtest[0:, 0:], columns=Xtest[0, 0:])
        print(Xtest.head(n=20))
        print(type(Xtest))

        # output: [20 rows x 1970 columns]
        # output: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

        Xtest['prediction' + str(pred_1) + str(label1)] = pred

        col_vals = pd.read_csv(str(set_val) + 'final_test_set_all_2.csv')
        col_vals = col_vals.columns.get_values()
        col_val_list = col_vals.tolist()
        col_val_list.extend(['prediction' + '_' + str(set_val) + '_' + label1 + '_' + str(epoch_val) + '_' + str(batch_val) + '_' + str(pred_1)])
        col_val_list.remove(label1)

        Xtest.columns = col_val_list
        Xtest.to_csv('mid_prediction' + '_' + str(set_val) + '_' + label1 + '_' + str(epoch_val) + '_' + str(batch_val) + '_' + str(pred_1) + '.csv')
        return None

    prediction_list2 = [1, 2, 3]
    for prediction2 in prediction_list2:
        neural_net_1(label_val, prediction2)

    sess.close()


neural_net(set_val=21, epoch_val=5,
           batch_val=24, label_val='label1')
```

However, when I run this code on ubuntu, I get the following in error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert bool to numpy.ndarray
```

in this line:

```
Xtest['prediction' + str(pred_1) + str(label1)] = pred
```

Also, in both instances,

the pred variable is:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

and the Xtest variable is:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

The mac is running python 3.6 and tensorflow 1.6 - cpu.

And the ubuntu is running python 3.5 and tensorflow 1.5 - gpu

I would much appreciate if someone could help me understand why the error occurs in one instance and not the other and how I could possibly fix it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To add column to the pandas dataframe you should do

```
col_name = 'prediction' + str(pred_1) + str(label1)
Xtest = Xtest.assign(col_name=pred)
```